# Creating multiple folders using Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I need to create 3 folders named AAA,BBB,CCC at location :c\temp\test

I tried the below codes:

```
$local = "C:\Temp\Test"
$Users = $local+"\AAA\",$local+"\BBB\",$local+"\CCC\"
New-Item -Item Type directory $Users
```

It is giving me error
New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

I also tried

```
$local = "C:\Temp\Test"
$Users = $local+"\AAA\",$local+"\BBB\",$local+"\CCC\"
md $Users
```

what am I missing here??

Comment: are the folders nested or do you want to have them in the same location `$local`?

Comment: I want to have them at same location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you definition of `$users` either put the variable inside the quotes or do the string concatenation in a subexpression e.g. `$()`. Also you had an extra space in the `ItemType` Parameter:

```
$local = "C:\Temp\Test"
$Users = "$local\AAA\","$local\BBB\","$local\CCC\"
New-Item -ItemType directory $Users
```

Answer (score 4):

[BenH's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44079528/45375) offers an effective solution.

**Why your command didn't work**:

Your problem was one of *operator precedence*:

```
$local+"\AAA\",$local+"\BBB\",$local+ "\CCC\"
```

was interpreted as:

```
$local + ("\AAA\",$local) + ("\BBB\",$local) +"\CCC\"
```

resulting in a *single string* rather than the desired *array*, because the LHS - `$local` is a *string*.

Perhaps surprisingly, `,`, the array-construction operator, has higher precedence than `+` - see [`Get-Help about_Operator_Precedence`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Operator_Precedence).

---

Therefore, **using `(...)` for precedence would have made your command work**:

```
$Users = ($local+"\AAA\"), ($local+"\BBB\"), ($local+"\CCC\")
```

---

Using **expandable (interpolating) strings (inside `"..."`)**, as in BenH's answer, is **more concise**, but still:

- requires defining *auxiliary variable* `$local` first
- requires referencing `$local` in *each* expandable (interpolating) string (`"..."`)

---

**A [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) alternative** is (`%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object`):

```
$Users = 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC' | % { "C:\Temp\$_\" }
```

Note that using a *pipeline* to achieve this is somewhat *slow*, but that won't matter in most cases.

---

Using the `foreach` statement is a little more verbose, but performs better:

```
$Users = foreach($name in 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC') { "C:\Temp\$name\" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the directory path values in an array and create new directories at a single run.

`@('D:/NewFolder','D:/NewFolder1/NewFolder_app','D:/NewFolder1/NewFolder_app_pool','C:/NewTestFolder101') | foreach {New-Item -Path $_ -ItemType Directory -Force}`

It will create all the directories at once.
For getting some directories as well as some files, declare two different arrays. The first one is for directories and the second one for the files. Rest of the script will be same except: Item-Type will be file instead of directory

Answer (score 0):

why not just use Mkdir $(001..10 | %{“testfolders-$_”})